# MVC Multiple forms in PartialView returns null on postback for except the 1st one listed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, html-helper, model-binding

Ok, I hope someone out there can help me out on this one (Thanks in advance!).  I'm using MVC4.

My ContractsModel contains (among other things) a list of ContractModel(s).  In my partial view, I loop though the list creating a form for each.  So far so good.  The issue is on postback.  The 1st form always posts back fine.  But the others (2, 3, 4, etc) always return null.

I've checked with debugging tools and confirmed that the rendered controls are appropriately named.

```
<select name="Contracts[0].OrganizationId" id="Contracts_0__OrganizationId">
<select name="Contracts[1].OrganizationId" id="Contracts_1__OrganizationId">
<select name="Contracts[2].OrganizationId" id="Contracts_2__OrganizationId">
```

I've also confirmed that client is indeed returning data to the server, but for some reason it does not seem to be getting attached back into the model that my ActionResult is expecting. Any ideas?

I've minimized my code for brevity.

Here are my models:

```
public class ContractsModel
{
    public ContractsModel()  
    {
        this.Contracts = new List<ContractModel>();

        this.OrganizationList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        this.ContractNumList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }

    public string ParentProjectId { get; set; }
    // etc, etc .....

    public List<ContractModel> Contracts { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> OrganizationList { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ContractNumList { get; set; }
}


public class ContractModel
{
    public string OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public string Organization { get; set; }
    public string ContractNumId { get; set; }
    public string ContractNum { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Controller Action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult _ContractsEdit(ContractsModel model)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        //blah, blah, blah....
    }

    return PartialView("Index", ProjectModel);
}
```

Here is my Partial View

```
@model Manager.Models.ContractsModel

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Contracts.Count(); i++)  
{
    var divId = "divContractsModelItem_" + (i + 1);
    var saveButtonId = "btnContractsEditSave_" + (i + 1);


    <div id = "@divId">  

        @using (Html.BeginForm("_ContractsEdit", "Projects", FormMethod.Post))
        {      
            <fieldset>
                <legend>General:</legend>

                <div>
                    <label>Contracting Organization:</label>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Contracts[i].OrganizationId, new SelectList(Model.OrganizationList, "value", "text", Model.Contracts[i].OrganizationId))
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label>Contract Number:</label>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Contracts[i].ContractNumId, new SelectList(Model.ContractNumList, "value", "text", Model.Contracts[i].ContractNumId))
                </div>

                <div>
                   <button id="@saveButtonId" type="submit">Save</button>
                </div>

            </fieldset>
        }
    </div> 

}
```

Comment: My guess is that you are running into the missing index problem (see [this blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)), due to the multiple forms.  Not sure what the best way is to solve the problem in this case, though.

Comment: (Other than the solution of going to a single form and determining which submit button was pressed and therefore which contract information was saved.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my comments helped you, I figured I would flesh them out as a full answer.

The problem with the model binding is that it does not allow you to skip array indexes - once one is skipped, it stops binding.  Your page has multiple forms, one for each Contract.  So the second and subsequent forms do not start at index 0 - they start at index 1 and then index 2 and so on.  Thus, the model binding fails immediately and you get a null object passed into your controller.

The simple solution is to move to a single form so that the model binding has access to all the indexes of the Contract objects, and then use extra code in the controller to determine which submit button was pressed.

I'm not certain that is the best solution, though, as having [multiple forms and submit buttons is better from an HTTP point of view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712398/multiple-forms-or-multiple-submits-in-a-page), since it reduces the amount of unnecessary data that is being posted to the server.  However, best is the enemy of good, and if a single form works...

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it looks like a disconnect between what each form represents and what the post controller method is expecting.  It looks like each form instance represents a single Contract, while your controller post method is expecting a full Contracts model.  Perhaps try changing your controller method to only take a Contract.

Comment: Already tried that... my controller still receives null.   Its interesting to note that the 1st form returns the model correctly, its the subsequent forms that return null.

Comment: It sort of makes sense, now that I think about it - the runtime is seeing that you are posting back Contract[2] ... but where's Contract[1] and Contract[0]?  For the first one, no problem - the runtime can figure out what to do.  There is an inherit mismatch between rendering many things and posting back one thing into a container of many things.

Comment: That makes sense... looks like going with Jason's suggestion is probably the easiest work around.