# Correlation between submit and beginform

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a problem when trying to render multiple models in a view.

Lets say that I have:

### Model

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public ArrayOfThings[] Things { get; set; }
```

### View

```
for (int i = 0; Model.Things.Count() > i; i++)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { Id = i }))
    {
        <p>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Things[i].IsDone, "Some Check")</p>

        <input type="submit" title="Delete" value="Check as Done" name="btn_submit" />
    }
}
```

How would I do this so that the input (submit) button would correlate with the right form? As it is, only the first form is being affected.

Comment: <input type="submit" title="Delete" value="Check as Done" name="btn_submit@i" id="btnSubmit@i" />

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: See [this question from Friday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613519/mvc-multiple-forms-in-partialview-returns-null-on-postback-for-except-the-1st-on/16614614#16614614).  Unfortunately, I currently don't know how to make this work with multiple forms, but that should give you a starting point.

Comment: Check these posts:

 - [ASP.NET MVC 3 Multiple Submit Inputs in One Form][1] 
 - [How do you handle multiple submit buttons in ASP.NET MVC Framework?][2]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258750/asp-net-mvc-3-multiple-submit-inputs-in-one-form
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework

Comment: It is not clear from your question whether you have multiple forms or a single form. Also it is not clear what model do you want to be posted to the server when this form is submitted. Also why are you setting the `id` to the index of the loop?

Comment: be sure you don't have nested forms. and what are you posting? you don't have something like `@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Things[i].Id)` inside the form.

Answer (score 0):

I think that maybe you need to change your mind. 
why you are creating new form??
you can use action link instead of submit button and send data through ActionLink parameters.

```
  <%=Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "Action", "Controller", new {id = "1"}, null)%>
```