# How to execute multiple forms inside form tag

Tags: php, mysql

plz suggest me how to execute multiple forms inside form tag
below is my code

there are two save button on same table and both executing different forms.
but the problem is taht when i click the save button it always execute the main form....

not executing the nested form......

below is my code plz help me.....

```
<section class="content">       
      <div class="box-body table-responsive">
        <?php                  
        foreach($rows as $row)
        {                       
        ?>          
         <table style="float:left;">

         <tr>
         <td style="float:left;">
         <form method="post" name="form2" action="exec_main.php?Edition=<?php echo $row["Edition"]; ?>&scheduletime=<?php echo $row["scheduletime"]; ?>">
         <table width="100%" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
         <tr>       
         <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><?php echo $row["Edition"]; ?></th>      
         </tr>  

         <form method="post"  action="exec_main_two.php?Edition=<?php echo $row["Edition"]; ?>" name="create">
         <tr>       
         <th colspan="2">
         <input type="text" style="background-color:transparent; width:60px; text-align:center; border:none;" name="pageno" required=""/>

        <input type="submit"  style="border:none;  text-align:center;width:50px; height:20px; background-color:transparent;"
        value="Save" onclick='this.style.visibility = "hidden"' />
         </th>      
         </tr>  
         </form>


         <tr>       
         <td colspan="2" class="scheduletime" style="text-align:center"><?php echo $row["scheduletime"]; ?></th>        
         </tr>  

        <td>Page No</td>
        <td>Actu.Time</td>       
        </tr>       

        <?php
        $userinput = 3;

        ?>
         <?php
            for($i=0; $i<$userinput; $i++)
            {
            ?>


        <tr>                    
          <td class="scheduletime" style="text-align:center">2</td> 
      <?php /*?>  <td class="scheduletime" style="text-align:center"><?php echo $row["scheduletime"]; ?></td> <?php */?>

    <?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['city']))
    {
     $city = make_safe($_SESSION['city']);  
    }                                                                                                           
    $Edition = $row['Edition']; 
    $sql = "SELECT actualtime FROM pagination where Edition = '$Edition' AND city = '$city'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $rows1 = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);    
    ?>

  <td class="actualtime">
    <?php if(!empty($rows1)) { ?>       
    <?php echo $rows1["actualtime"]; }  else{ ?>

<input type="submit"  name="save" style="border:none; text-align:center;width:50px; height:20px; background-color:transparent;"value="Save" 
onclick='this.style.visibility = "hidden"' />
            </td>
            <?php } ?>
    </tr>   
    <?php } ?>
        </table>
        </form>
        </td></tr></table>
        <?php } ?>  
     </div> 
       </section>
```

Comment: You can't nest forms, form elements inside a `form` tag will always be  actioned by the value provided to the `action` attribute of the form. In this case presumably the "main" or parent form tag

Comment: Duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms

Comment: Well look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712398/multiple-forms-or-multiple-submits-in-a-page

Answer (score 0):

U can not put form tag inside one existing form.