# Get variable in while loop based on what user chooses?

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

I want to delete a single post from deleteupload.php hence I want to access product_id which is the unique identifier of each row after submission. I have wrapped every product in a form element and a submit button. So the page has multiple form elements.

This is my code:

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($loop))
 {
  $proID = $row['product_id'];

 echo "<table border='0' width='100%' align='center' class='centrebox'><tr>
 <td width='25%'>".($row['product_name']) . "</td> " . "
 <td width='35%'>".($row['product_disc'])."</td>";

 echo '<td width="40%"><img width="100%" height="300"  src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['product_image'] ).'"/></td></tr>
 <td><form method="post" action="deleteupload.php">
 <input type="submit" name="$proID" value="Delete"></form></td></table><br>';

}
```

This while loop iterates through the sql table and echos the columns (product_name, product_disc, and product_image).

Comment: That should do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could put this in your html/php

```
       echo '<td width="40%"><img width="100%" height="300"  src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['product_image'] ).'"/></td></tr>
             <td><form name="form' . $proID . '" class="del_forms" method="post" action="deleteupload.php">
             <input type = "hidden" name="del_item" value="' . $proID .'" />
             <input type="submit" value="Delete" /></form></td></table><br>';
```

and in your `deleteupload.php` you would pick up the `$proID;` as a `$_POST['del_item'];` variable. Assuming `$proID;` is the ID number of the item you want to have deleted.

Note that you should be using `mysqli` not `mysql` as `mysql` is regarded as vulnerable to attack. You should also escape/sanitize the `$_POST` variable to help prevent inject attack.

```
  (int) $_POST['del_item'];
```

should achieve that in this case as long as the IDs are already integers. (Won't work if they contain letters.)

You might find this of interest as well: [Multiple Forms or Multiple Submits in a Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712398/multiple-forms-or-multiple-submits-in-a-page)

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border='0' width='100%' align='center' class='centrebox'>
<?php 
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($loop))
 { 
  $proID = $row['product_id'];
?>
 <tr>
 <td width='25%'><?php ($row['product_name'])?></td> 
 <td width='35%'><?php ($row['product_disc']) ?></td>
 <td width='35%'>
    <a href="deleteupload.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $proID ?>"></a>   
 </td>

<?php } ?>
</table>

**deleteupload.php**

<?php
if($_GET['action']=='delete'){

    delete query
}
?>
```