# Always same value for id in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web, controller

guys. I use Asp.net MVC and C#. I have 2 buttons for every object on page. First button for add in shop cart, second button for view details. So this buttons generate for every object in my model. I want to pass id field into controller, but i always got id = 1 in action. How i can pass the right id? Can someone explain ?

Here is form:

```
@model IEnumerable<StickerOn.Models.Sticker>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("RedirectButton", "Sticker", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div style="margin-left:50px">
        <div class="body-content">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count() - 1; i++)
            {
                <div class="row">
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <img src="@item.ImgToReprs" alt="..." width="200" height="100">
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h3>@item.Name</h3>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.id)
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@item.id" />
                                    <p><button type="submit" id="@item.id" name="submitButton" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i></button><input type="submit" name="submitButton" class="btn btn-default" value="..." /></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RedirectButton(int? id,string submitButton)
        {
            var g = Request.Form["id"];
            switch(submitButton)
            {
                case "...":
                    return Details(1);
                case "":
                    break;
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: I imagine that since  `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="@item.id" /> `is repeated many times inside the same form the first value is taken.

Comment: The easiest thing to try is to repeat the form control too

Comment: I think if i will use many form control, my code will be so big and clumsy

Comment: @SBFrancies, how i can avoid it and pass the right id?

Comment: You could use an action link and specify the parameters.

Comment: @SBFrancies, yeah i know. but is it possible to use without action link? i need buttons...

Comment: Do you need buttons or do you just need it to look like a button? You can always style the link with css.

Comment: i need something that will looks like basket for buy and "..." for view details

Comment: I have added to my answer an option which would let you keep using your current styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that in each loop you are creating a control with the name "id" and on form submission the value in the first one is being picked up. I see a few options.

One option is to create a new form in each loop:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName"))
    {
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="@item.ImgToReprs" alt="..." width="200" height="100">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>@item.Name</h3>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.id)
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@item.id" />
                        <p><button type="submit" id="@item.id" name="submitButton" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i></button><input type="submit" name="submitButton" class="btn btn-default" value="..." /></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Another option would be to use action links instead of the form submission. These might look like:

```
@ActionLink("Text", "ActionName", ("ControllerName",) new { id=item.id }, new { @class="btn" })
```

A third way which would allow you to keep your present styling with little effort:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Action","Controller", new {id=item.id })"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i></a>

<input type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Action","Controller", new {id=item.id })';" value="..." />
```

Comment: can you tell me, is it normal to create form for every object?

Comment: If it's the best way to achieve what you want then it should be fine, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712398/multiple-forms-or-multiple-submits-in-a-page