# Tie elements to multiple forms?

Tags: html

On my strictly HTML site, I have multiple forms that all need access to one select element, in order to send its context via POST to the server. I'd like to not resort to copying that element into each form. Is there any way of tying that element to multiple forms in HTML?

Comment: Is that can help you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712398/multiple-forms-or-multiple-submits-in-a-page

Comment: Also some info in w3schools 
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_form_steps.asp

Comment: Sadly it does not, but thanks for the links