# how to get the form url from jquery forms

Tags: javascript, laravel-9

I Have this form with laravel and the js form also ,So the Question how can i know url of the post when i hit save

This form has many forms and it with js posting it

note: i wanna know jsut how can i know the form data so i can make it with jquery with if satatment if some thing post this url or what is the right way to do it

The blade.php file

```
<div class="content-header row">
            <div class="content-header-left col-md-9 col-12 mb-2">
                <div class="row breadcrumbs-top">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <h2 class="content-header-title float-left mb-0">Account Settings</h2>
                        <div class="breadcrumb-wrapper">
                            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Pages</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="breadcrumb-item active"> Account Settings
                                </li>
                            </ol>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-header-right text-md-right col-md-3 col-12 d-md-block d-none">
                <div class="form-group breadcrumb-right">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn-icon btn btn-primary btn-round btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i data-feather="grid"></i></button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"><a class="dropdown-item" href="app-todo.html"><i class="mr-1" data-feather="check-square"></i><span class="align-middle">Todo</span></a><a class="dropdown-item" href="app-chat.html"><i class="mr-1" data-feather="message-square"></i><span class="align-middle">Chat</span></a><a class="dropdown-item" href="app-email.html"><i class="mr-1" data-feather="mail"></i><span class="align-middle">Email</span></a><a class="dropdown-item" href="app-calendar.html"><i class="mr-1" data-feather="calendar"></i><span class="align-middle">Calendar</span></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-body">
            <!-- account setting page -->
            <section id="page-account-settings">
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- left menu section -->
                    <div class="col-md-3 mb-2 mb-md-0">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column nav-left">
                            <!-- general -->
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link active" id="account-pill-general" data-toggle="pill" href="#account-vertical-general" aria-expanded="true">
                                    <i data-feather="user" class="font-medium-3 mr-1"></i>
                                    <span class="font-weight-bold">General</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <!-- change password -->
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" id="account-pill-password" data-toggle="pill" href="#account-vertical-password" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <i data-feather="lock" class="font-medium-3 mr-1"></i>
                                    <span class="font-weight-bold">Change Password</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
               
                            <!-- notification -->
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" id="account-pill-notifications" data-toggle="pill" href="#account-vertical-notifications" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <i data-feather="bell" class="font-medium-3 mr-1"></i>
                                    <span class="font-weight-bold">Notifications</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!--/ left menu section -->

                    <!-- right content section -->
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="tab-content">
                                    <!-- general tab -->
                                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="account-vertical-general" aria-labelledby="account-pill-general" aria-expanded="true">
                                        
                                        <!-- form -->
                                        <form class="validate-form mt-2">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label for="account-username">Username</label>
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="account-username" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="johndoe" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
        
                                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label for="account-e-mail">E-mail</label>
                                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="account-e-mail" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="granger007@hogward.com" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                         
                                                <div class="col-12 mt-75">
                                                    <div class="alert alert-warning mb-50" role="alert">
                                                        <h4 class="alert-heading">Your email is not confirmed. Please check your inbox.</h4>
                                                        <div class="alert-body">
                                                            <a href="javascript: void(0);" class="alert-link">Resend confirmation</a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-12">
                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2 mr-1">Save changes</button>
                                                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mt-2">Cancel</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                        <!--/ form -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!--/ general tab -->

                                    <!-- change password -->
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="account-vertical-password" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="account-pill-password" aria-expanded="false">
                                        <!-- form -->
                                        <form class="validate-form" action="{{ route('update') }}" method="POST"">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label for="current_password">{{ __('Current Password') }}</label>
                                                        <div class="input-group form-password-toggle input-group-merge">
                                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="current_password" name="current_password" placeholder="Current Password" />
                                                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                                                <div class="input-group-text cursor-pointer">
                                                                    <i data-feather="eye"></i>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label for="password">{{ __('New Password') }}</label>
                                                        <div class="input-group form-password-toggle input-group-merge">
                                                            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="New Password" />
                                                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                                                <div class="input-group-text cursor-pointer">
                                                                    <i data-feather="eye"></i>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label for="password_confirmation">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>
                                                        <div class="input-group form-password-toggle input-group-merge">
                                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password_confirmation" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
                                                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                                                <div class="input-group-text cursor-pointer"><i data-feather="eye"></i></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-12">
                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-1 mt-1">Save changes</button>
                                                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mt-1">Cancel</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                        <!--/ form -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!--/ change password -->


                                    <!-- notifications -->
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="account-vertical-notifications" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="account-pill-notifications" aria-expanded="false">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <h6 class="section-label mx-1 mb-2">Activity</h6>
                                            <div class="col-12 mb-2">
                                                <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" checked id="accountSwitch1" />
                                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="accountSwitch1">
                                                        Email me when someone comments onmy article
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-12 mb-2">
                                                <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" checked id="accountSwitch2" />
                                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="accountSwitch2">
                                                        Email me when someone answers on my form
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-12 mb-2">
                                                <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="accountSwitch3" />
                                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="accountSwitch3">Email me hen someone follows me</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <h6 class="section-label mx-1 mt-2">Application</h6>
                                            <div class="col-12 mt-1 mb-2">
                                                <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" checked id="accountSwitch4" />
                                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="accountSwitch4">News and announcements</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-12 mb-2">
                                                <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" checked id="accountSwitch6" />
                                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="accountSwitch6">Weekly product updates</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-12 mb-75">
                                                <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="accountSwitch5" />
                                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="accountSwitch5">Weekly blog digest</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-12">
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2 mr-1">Save changes</button>
                                                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mt-2">Cancel</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--/ notifications -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--/ right content section -->
                </div>
            </section>
            <!-- / account setting page -->

        </div>
```

this is the js file

```
$(function () {
  'use strict';

  // variables
  var form = $('.validate-form');

  
  // jQuery Validation
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------
  if (form.length) {
    form.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this);

      $this.validate({
        rules: {
          username: {
            required: true
          },
          email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
          },
          current_password: {
            required: true
          },
          'password': {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6
          },
          'password_confirmation': {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            equalTo: '#password'
          }
        }
      });
      $this.on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: You can add a custom value for each button like `value="form1"` then check them to know which button is clicked and which form should be processed. So you need to listen to click event on them, like `$(".btn-primary").click(function(e){...}`. And after preventing default event check that value like `if ($(this).attr("value")=="form1")`.

Comment: Have you check out the other posts like this https://stackoverflow.com/q/8712398/4650866